# How to make button in OverflowSet execute?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I get a button in Office ui fabric's OverflowSet do something.
The example from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/overflowset has the onClick event which never fires.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BaseComponent, css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities';
import { CommandBarButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { SearchBox } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/SearchBox';
import { IOverflowSetItemProps, OverflowSet } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/OverflowSet';

import * as stylesImport from './OverflowSet.Example.scss';
const styles: any = stylesImport;

export class OverflowSetCustomExample extends BaseComponent<any, any> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <OverflowSet
        items={[
          {
            key: 'upload',
            name: 'Upload',
            icon: 'Upload',
            onClick: () => {
              console.log("this never happens");
            }
          }
        ]}
        overflowItems={[]}
        onRenderOverflowButton={this._onRenderOverflowButton}
        onRenderItem={this._onRenderItem}
      />
    );
  }

  private _onRenderItem(item: IOverflowSetItemProps): JSX.Element {
    if (item.onRender) {
      return item.onRender(item);
    }
    return <CommandBarButton iconProps={{ iconName: item.icon }} menuProps={item.subMenuProps} text={item.name} />;
  }

  private _onRenderOverflowButton(overflowItems: any[] | undefined): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <CommandBarButton className={css(styles.overflowButton)} menuIconProps={{ iconName: 'More' }} menuProps={{ items: overflowItems! }} />
    );
  }
}
```

the click event never fires. How do I use the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are providing an `onRenderItem` callback, you are taking over the component’s default render method. Therefore, you have to apply the `onClick` prop yourself directly:

```
  private _onRenderItem(item: IOverflowSetItemProps): JSX.Element {
    if (item.onRender) {
      return item.onRender(item);
    }
    //
    // this now returns the button with the onClick handler applied
    //
    return <CommandBarButton onClick={item.onClick} iconProps={{ iconName: item.icon }} menuProps={item.subMenuProps} text={item.name} />;
  }
```